# Having problems reading a files input as characters

Tags: java, arrays, file, input, char

I am trying to create a constructor for a class that accepts two parameters that are files and put the information in the files in my array fields

my code for the program looks like this:

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
 import java.io.*;

  public class Chapter7ALabDemo
 {
     public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException
 {
     File file;
     Scanner readKey;
     Scanner readAnswers;
     String str;
      int numQuestions;
     DriverExam student;
     int [] missedQuestions;

     Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

      System.out.println("Enter the name of the file that is the test key ");
      str = keyboard.nextLine();
      file = new File(str);
      readKey = new Scanner(file);

      System.out.println("Enter the name of the file with the student answers.");
      str = keyboard.nextLine();
      file = new File(str);
      readAnswers = new Scanner(file);

      System.out.println("How many test questions are there?");
      numQuestions = keyboard.nextInt();

      student = new DriverExam(readKey, readAnswers, numQuestions);
      missedQuestions = student.questionsMissed();

      System.out.println(student);
      if (student.passed())
          System.out.println("The student passed.");
      else
          System.out.println("The student did not pass.");

      System.out.println("The student got " + student.totalCorrect() + " answers correct.");
     System.out.println("The student got " + student.totalIncorrect() + " answers incorrect."); 
     System.out.println("The following questions were missed by the student: ");
     student.printMissed(missedQuestions);
 }
}
```

My constructor should instantiate the arrays to a given size and stores data read from the file into the answer key array and stores data read from another file into the student answer array.
 my constructor inside my class that I tried looks like this Note: I only did the first one to show)

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class DriverExam
 {
    private static char[] answerKey;
    private static char[] studentAns;

    public DriverExam(Scanner readKey,Scanner readAnswers,int numQuestions)
    {
        answerKey = new char[numQuestions];
        for (int i = 0; readKey.hasNext() && i < numQuestions; i++)
             answerKey[i] = readKey.nextChar();


    }
```

The only problem is that I'm having trouble reading a character at a Time. the answer and key looks like this:
A
B
B

and so on.

I have read on here about using the FileInputStream but we have not got to that in our studys.  I get an error about cannot read a string as a char. What am Suppose to do then? Also, I thought there isn't a way to convert a string into a character?

Comment: The input files llook like this:

Comment: The input files look like this:
     A\n
     B\n
     B\n

Answer (score 1):

You can try this `answerKey[i] = readKey.next().charAt(0)` with necessary boundary/null checks.